# Correct way to redirect user to different routes based on authentication in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my ReactJS app, routes are configured in below way:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isLoggedin: false
    }
    
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('name'))
    {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedin: true
      })}
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <>
      
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=><Login isLoggedin={this.state.isLoggedin} />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" render={<Login isLoggedin={this.state.isLoggedin} />} />
        <Route exact path="/home" render={()=><Home isLoggedin={this.state.isLoggedin} />} />
        
      </Switch></>
      
    );
  }
}
```

In Login.js:

```
class Login extends React.Component{
    render(){
        if(this.props.isLoggedin) return <Redirect to="/home" />;
        return(
            <h1>Login here</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

In Home.js:

```
class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        if(!this.props.isLoggedin) return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        return(
            <h1>Home</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

So what this code will do is that when the user visits the `/`, it would first go to Login component and as soon as `isLoggedin` is set to true, it would redirect the user to Home.js. Same thing would happen if user is not loggedin and he tries to access `/home`, he would be redirected to `/login`. Since I am using local storage, all of this would happen in flash of eye. It is also working just fine.

But I doubt if it is the best method to achieve my goal. I want to know if there is any more advisable method to do this.

Thanks!!

Comment: It is ok but don't forget to hash sensitive information when setting to LocalStorage, like passwords for example. You can use JWt for this: https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more advisable method would be to decouple the auth checks from the components and abstract this into custom route components.

PrivateRoute - if the user is authenticated then a regular `Route` is rendered and the props are passed through, otherwise redirect to the "/login" path for user to authenticate.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, ...props }) => {
  return isLoggedIn ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```

AnonymousRoute - Basically the inverse of the private route. If the user is already authenticated then redirect them to the "/home" path, otherwise render  a route and pass the route props through.

```
const AnonymousRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, ...props }) => {
  return isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Route {...props} />;
};
```

From here you render the `Login` and `Home` components into their respective custom route components.

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute
    isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} // *
    path="/home"
    component={Home}
  />
  <AnonymousRoute
    isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} // *
    path={["/login", "/"]}
    component={Login}
  />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit correct-way-to-redirect-user-to-different-routes-based-on-authentication-in-reac]

**** NOTE:** The `isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}` prop is only required here since the `isLoggedIn` state resides in the `App` component. A typical React application would store the auth state in a React Context or in global state like Redux, and thus wouldn't need to be ***explicitly*** passed via props, it could be accessed from within the custom route component.*

Full sandbox code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, ...props }) => {
  return isLoggedIn ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};

const AnonymousRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, ...props }) => {
  return isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Route {...props} />;
};

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Login here</h1>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.login}>
          Log in
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.logout}>
          Log out
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn")) {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.isLoggedIn !== this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", JSON.stringify(this.state.isLoggedIn));
    }
  }

  logInHandler = () => this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
  logOutHandler = () => this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>Authenticated: {this.state.isLoggedIn ? "Yes" : "No"}</div>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">/</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/login">log in</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
            path="/home"
            render={() => <Home logout={this.logOutHandler} />}
          />
          <AnonymousRoute
            isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
            path={["/login", "/"]}
            render={() => <Login login={this.logInHandler} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```